# Check TreeView has any Node selected or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a treeview control on my aspx page and a button.on the basis of treeview node selection I want to show and hide the button.but when initially page loads there is no any seleceted node that's in if condition it is generating exception.Can anyone tell me that how can i find that is there any node selected or not ?

```
  //Here I want to check is there any selected node "ApplicationTree.Nodes.Count>0"
         <%if(ApplicationTree.Nodes.Count>0)
               {%>                         
                            <%
//Here it is generating exception because initially no any node is selected
              IsReviewPending = view_access.IsWaitingForViewAccess(ApplicationTree.SelectedNode.Value, Session["empCode"].ToString());
              if (IsReviewPending)
              {
                  CanReviewAccess = true;
              }
              else 
              {
                  CanReviewAccess = false;
              }                    
                                      %>  
                  <%if(CanReviewAccess)
                    {%>
                <asp:Button ID="btn_Review_Access" OnClick="btn_Review_Access_Click" runat="server" BackColor="#C6304A" ForeColor="White" Text="Confirm Access Review" Width="200px"  CssClass="center3" />                 
                  <%} %>

                                 <%} %>
```

Comment: Its because you are trying to access the value of that node which is null. May be introduce a null check can fix your issue. I have no context awareness but do you want to may be completely ignore this operation if the SelectedNode is null? If so introduce if(ApplicationTree.SelectedNode!- null) will solve your problem

Comment: No,I've tried this  but same exception !!! Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :)

```
    //Here is my Code
     <%
             bool HasSelectedNode = false;
//i iterated through the overall nodes of the tree and checked any of the node is selected or not 
             for (int i = 0; i < ApplicationTree.Nodes.Count;i++ )
             {
             if(ApplicationTree.Nodes[i].Selected==true)
             {
                 HasSelectedNode = true;
             }
             }
              %>
         <%if(HasSelectedNode)
           {%>                         
                        <%
          IsReviewPending = view_access.IsWaitingForViewAccess(ApplicationTree.SelectedNode.Value, Session["empCode"].ToString());
             //  IsReviewPending = true;
          if (IsReviewPending)
          {
              CanReviewAccess = true;
          }
          else 
          {
              CanReviewAccess = false;
          }                    
                                  %>  
              <%if(CanReviewAccess)
                {%>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_Review_Access" OnClick="btn_Review_Access_Click" runat="server" BackColor="#C6304A" ForeColor="White" Text="Confirm Access Review" Width="200px"  CssClass="center3" />                 
              <%} %>

                             <%} %>
```